# How do I pass a specific ca cert or path to the Sekken constructor?

Tags: ruby, openssl, savon, sekken

When I try to create a new Sekken client, it throws an OpenSSL error that there is a self signed certificate in the chain.

```
require 'sekken'
url = "https://bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com/webservicesapi/9.0/xgservices.svc?wsdl"
client = Sekken.new(url)
```

I can duplicate the error from OpenSSL, and I can fix it by passing the location for the SSL cert store.

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443`

errors with return code 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain) but

`openssl s_client -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443`

returns code 0 (ok)

So I'm not sure how or what I need to do to pass that cert path to Sekken to use for the openssl check. Sekken does provide for an [HTTPClient](http://savonrb.com/version3/http-configuration.html) gem object to be passed to the constructor, so maybe something there? But I just can't quite get my head around this. Or possibly an environment variable? Does anyone have any ideas about how I can get the Sekken constructor to use a specific cert path or cert?

Machine is Ubuntu 14.04 x64, ruby via rvm is ruby 2.1.1p76, sekken is installed via a Gemfile from github.

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: "... I can fix it by passing the location for the SSL cert store" - that's somewhat odd. Is the self signed in `/etc/ssl/certs`?

Comment: Strike that comment... The server is mis-configured. Its sending the CA Root (`Trustwave Extended Validation CA, Level 3`) in the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ok, looks like you can pass an instance of an HTTPClient to the Sekken constructor. But there's a bug in the constructor that keeps it from using the passed client. I hacked my way around it, but hopefully the owner will fix it better? https://github.com/savonrb/sekken/issues/10

Once that is fixed, this is how I solved the problem. I created an instance of the HTTPClient then added the Trustwave root CA cert to the instance cert store and passed that to the Sekken constructor.

```
    require 'sekken'
    require 'httpclient'

    url = "https://bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com/webservicesapi/9.0/xgservices.svc?wsdl"
    # this is the secure trust CA
    cert = "/etc/ssl/certs/stca.pem"

    http = HTTPClient.new
    http.ssl_config.cert_store.add_file cert

    client = Sekken.new(url, http)
```

Answer (score 0):

> openssl s_client -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443

Ignore this. The server is misconfigured, and its sending the CA Root. The server should only send the server's certificate and *all* intermediates required to build a path to a root. Its up to the client to trust the root.

Here's what your command should look like (avoiding the CA Zoo in `/etc/ssl/certs`, and trusting only what is needed):

```
openssl s_client -connect bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443 -CAfile <Trustwave Root CA>
```

You can get `<Trustwave Root CA>` from [Trustwave SSL - Support - Root Download](https://ssl.trustwave.com/support/support-root-download.php). Get the one named *Trustwave Extended Validation CA* in PEM format.

Here's what it looks like when using the *Trustwave Extended Validation CA* (`evca.crt`). Notice the `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` at the tail of the output.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443 -CAfile evca.crt 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = SecureTrust Corporation, CN = SecureTrust CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Illinois, L = Chicago, O = "Trustwave Holdings, Inc.", CN = "Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2", emailAddress = ca@trustwave.com
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.lexisnexis.com, O = LexisNexis, L = Miamisburg, ST = Ohio, C = US
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.lexisnexis.com/O=LexisNexis/L=Miamisburg/ST=Ohio/C=US
   i:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
   i:/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
   i:/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=*.lexisnexis.com/O=LexisNexis/L=Miamisburg/ST=Ohio/C=US
issuer=/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3569 bytes and written 831 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 684051C7B37B4A255AE51BFC67CFC4BF...
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 53C559C9F85A6CB1788BFC20E1A1997C...
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1399081838
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

> So I'm not sure how or what I need to do to pass that cert path to Sekken to use for the openssl check.

All you need to do is specify *Trustwave Extended Validation CA* (`evca.crt`) as the root to use in Sekken when building the validation path. I'm not a Sekken guy, but I know how to do it in other languages and libraries like .Net, Java, OpenSSL, PERL, Python, etc.

Since you specified the Ruby tag, here's a test script I was using for some PKI testing with Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://bridgerinsighteu.lexisnexis.com:443')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

# Enable SSL/TLS ?
if uri.scheme == "https"
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  http.ca_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "evca.crt")
end

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
http.request(req)
```

---

This is just bike shedding... You have the *Trustwave Extended Validation CA* in `/etc/ssl/certs`. If the certificate was missing, then `s_client` would have failed when using `CApath`.

Trustwave has proven itself to be very untrustworthy. In the past, it facilitated interception of all SSL/TLS traffic by issuing certificates for domains *not* under the control of the person who wanted the certificates.

"Trust" is tricky to define. One of the better definitions I have seen is "X expects Y to do Z". That is, X expects or trusts Y to do Z because (1) Y says it does Z and (2) X accepts or approves of Z.

If you plug in PKI: "Users expect CAs to follow their CP and CPS". CP is "Certification Practice" and its *policy*; and CPS Is [Certification Practice Statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_Practice_Statement) and its *procedure*. So the CP and CPS specifies how the CA operates by defining policies (CP), and procedures to implement or enforce the policies (CPS).

If Trustwave followed their own published policies and procedures, then Trustwave would *not* have issued the certificates to intercept the SSL/TLS traffic. Trustwave did *not* follow their own policies and procedures, so they have proven themselves to be untrustworthy. Quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: Thanks jww, I get all that. I understand the difference between cert stores and certs and passing ca_path and ca_cert. I've written test code in ruby even using the HTTPClient gem that Sekken uses. However, what I don't know is how to get Sekken to use a specific cert store in creating the HTTPClient object. From what I can tell, Sekken instantiates the HTTPClient object as part of the init process for Sekken.
That's why I rolled back your changes to remove Sekken and Savon from the original question title.

Comment: As you have changed the title of my question, you've done a great job of answering it. 

However, that's not the question I have. My question is how to do I have the Sekken constructor use a different cert or cert store. Right now I'm looking at creating a new class that inherits from HTTPClient and overrides the init method to use the cert store or cert i need and passing that to the Sekken constructor. It feels like swatting a fly with a hammer and is a bit advanced for my nascent ruby skills, but i suppose a good way to learn something more about ruby.

Comment: @Fez - Removing the Savon and Sekken tag from the title did not change the question. If "... I'm not sure how or what I need to do to pass that cert path to Sekken to use for the openssl check... Any ideas?" is *not* the question, then please update your question.

Comment: @Fez - believe it or not, sometimes its not easy to determine what someone is asking. An open ended question like "Any ideas?" is tough to work with. Sorry I could not be of better assistance to you.

Comment: that's precisely the question, how do I go about getting Sekken to use a specific ca path or cert in it's constructor? 

I'll edit the question to remove the 'any ideas?' part, change the question to 'does anyone have any ideas for how to pass the cert path to Sekken to use for the openssl check?' 

But this is still a question primarily about how the Sekken constructor works.

Comment: and thank you for adding the Sekken tag, I didn't have enough points to do it.